# How to create a JSON Object {"x":"16","y":"XXXX"}.... in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, json, loops

Given the following:

What I would like to happen:
1. Find all Span TAGS with class="location"
2. Loop through these and create a JSON string to post to the server

```
// Determine how many there are
var postText = $("#container").html();
var numFound = $("span.location").length;
var countVar = 0;

//Loop through all the Locations
$( "span.location" ).each( function() {

    // Keep a count
    countVar = countVar + 1;
    // Send at the end
    if (countVar == numFound) {
        // Send some JSON object to the server [{"locationID":"16","locationDesc":"XXXX"}....]
    }

});
```

Can someone help me understand how to create a JSON object like:     `[{"locationID":"16","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"111","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"12","locationDesc":"XXXX"}, {"locationID":"11","locationDesc":"XXXX"}]`

I'd like to build this object via a LOOP, so some way to append over and over.

thxs

Comment: Are you asking how to build the JavaScript object, or how to serialize it as JSON?

Comment: I didn't realize those were two different things? I'm look to make the above so I can POST it to the server with JQUERY

Comment: Do you have an example of the data source this stuff is coming from? To show an example loop we'd need to know the structure of the data you want to create this JSON string from.

Comment: @Jimmy, it's been update

Comment: What is the structure of the actual data, though? How are `locationID` and `locationDesc` determined for each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON does not have objects. JavaScript has objects, and JSON has strings. Use [`json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) to convert between the two.

Comment: Do I need something else like json2.js if I already have JQUERY?

Comment: Presumably there's some some of encoder/decoder in jQuery, but I've never used it.

Comment: JSON2.js tells me how to access the string. I'm not see how to create this string, especially while looping to build it. ideas?

Comment: You *don't* create the string. You create the object in JavaScript, and then shove it through `stringify()` to turn it into a string.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this in a loop, where it appends and builds the string?